# Bitmap not adapting the changes when re-converted from BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, graphic

I have an array of 9 bitmaps split from a Bitmap. What I'm trying to do is changing the `Bitmap` `arrayList` to `Drawable` `arrayList`, applying `porterDuffColorFilter` to every `Drawable` of the array then converting them again to Bitmap. The `colorFilter` can be seen when I use `setImageDrawable` and use any of the `Drawable` from the array but when I use setImageBitmap with any of the newly converted Bitmap, there are no changes at all.

Code I'm using:

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> changeColor(ArrayList<Bitmap> smallImages) {
        ArrayList<Drawable> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(9);
        for(int i=0;i<smallImages.size();i++){
            arrayList.add(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),smallImages.get(i)));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
            Drawable d = arrayList.get(i);
            d.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            arrayList.set(i,d);
            //I've also tried arrayList.get(i).setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);                
        }
        imageView.setImageDrawable(arrayList.get(4)); //this works great
        smallImages.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
            smallImages.add(((BitmapDrawable)arrayList.get(i)).getBitmap());
        }
        // imageView.setImageBitmap(smallImages.get(4)); 
        // this doesn't work, same as before
        return smallImages;
    }
```

I've searched various methods to convert it using an other method but all are using the same method for `BitmapDrawable`. Maybe I'm missing something, Please help.

Comment: why do you need `ArrayList<Bitmap>`? whats wrong in `ArrayList<Drawable>`?

Comment: @pskink to combine all the Bitmap into one again, see my previous question where you'd suggested `PorterDuffColorFilter`.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/2HhQ3peR

Comment: @pskink I was stuck for days with nothing, got too many code to work with by Lalit and your few lines of code work instant. Man, you are truly a genius. Thanks is a very small word. you just made me achieve something no one have achieved till date. Thanks.

Comment: sure, you are welcome